# Plotly / python how to specify config options when displaying HTML?

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-python

Am trying to remove the ModeBar in a plotly plot that's generated in Python and displayed in HTML with JS.
Per the documentation, you can specify a config such as:

```
config = dict({'displayModeBar': False})
fig.show(config=config)
```

But am exporting the fig to json with
`graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)` (not using the .show() function)

And then displaying it with JS:

```
<script>
 var graphs = {{graphJSON | safe}};
 Plotly.newPlot('graph',graphs,{});
</script>
```

I tried specifying a config in the newPlot call but no luck, it seems to be ignored:

```
Plotly.newPlot('graph',graphs,{},{displayModeBar: false});
```

How can I specify config options when converting to json? Is there any other way to get rid of the ModeBar (the top bar that is displayed on mouseover)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? The config in JavaScript is ignored as you reported. This must be an issue when plot is generated in Python.

Comment: I am using CSS to remove the toolbar as a temporary solution with a change to the following class: "modebar-container {display: none; }"

Answer (score 5):

Had similar issue where config was ignored when using newPlot(). Attaching the config object straight to graph data worked for me.

```js
<script>
 var graphs = {{graphJSON | safe}};
 graphs.config = {'displayModeBar': false}
 Plotly.newPlot('graph', graphs);
</script>
```

Comment: This is pretty horrifying considering the documentation for newPlot(...)(https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/) which clearly states that you can provide the configuration as the last argument. I tried that but it was ignored, attaching a config property to the graphs object worked.

Answer (score 1):

Plotly.newPlot('graph', {...graphs, config: {displayModeBar: false}});

This is how, I was able to solve this issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/), you want to remove that empty `{}` and write this instead

```
Plotly.newPlot('graph',graphs,{displayModeBar: false});
```

Comment: The config in JavaScript is ignored for some reason. This must be an issue when plot is generated in Python.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get this to work for layout options and config options without any hacky extra code in the HTML.**
The key is remembering what `render_template` accepts as parameters (*valid json*).

1. Convert the *image*, *layout*, and *config* dictionaries to json. Your "image" here could also be a "graph_object" or "figure".

```
image = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
layout = json.dumps({'margin': dict(l=0, r=0, t=50, b=0)})
config = json.dumps({'displaylogo': False, 'modeBarButtonsToAdd': ['drawclosedpath', 'eraseshape']})
```

2. Pass those to `render_template`.

```
return render_template('example.html', image=image, layout=layout, config=config)
```

3. Use all three in your `html` template, following the safe convention if you trust the data.

```
<script>
Plotly.newPlot('image', {{ image | safe }}, {{ layout | safe }}, {{ config | safe }});
</script>
```

**Put that all together, and your final code would look something like this**

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create():
    image = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    layout = json.dumps({'margin': dict(l=0, r=0, t=50, b=0)})
    config = json.dumps({'displaylogo': False, 'modeBarButtonsToAdd': ['drawclosedpath', 'eraseshape']})
    return render_template('example.html', image=image, layout=layout, config=config)
```

```
<body>
  <div class="chart" id="image">
    <script>
      Plotly.newPlot('image', {{ image | safe }}, {{ layout | safe }}, {{ config | 
safe }});
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
```

That's it! No need to set the config/layout somewhere other than the place where you set your figure.